# Binding a jquery generated hidden field to angularjs model in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a captcha directive using the http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html jquery plugin.

I'm relatively new to angularjs, and can't seem to find a way to do this. Basically I want a captcha to verify a human is signing up for their account.  Calling element.realperson() will generate a hidden input field with some hashed value that I need to compare to the entered input on the serverside.

So if I call this very basic and incomplete directive, it will bind the newUser.captchaInput model to the input form, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to grab the hidden field value $('#captcha_hash').val() and somehow include it in the form data.  Ideally as newUser.captchaHash.

```
angular.module('vah').directive("captcha", ->
  restrict: "A"
  require: '?ngModel'
  link: (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) ->
    return if !ngModel

    optionsObj = {
      length: 5
    }

  element.realperson(optionsObj)

  # need to bind $('#captcha_hash').val() to a newUser.captchaHash model, or 
  add the model to that generated input field.

)

<input captcha id="defaultReal" ng-model="newUser.captchaInput">
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you like reCaptcha you can try using [VividCortex/angular-recaptcha](https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha).

Comment: It's ok @MichaelRobinson. You can undo it by clicking in the arrow again :)

Comment: Vote is locked in unless answer is edited (thanks for the tip though :P)

Answer (score 0):

Working code, thanks to some help from someone on a different programming forum. It's definitely not ideal, and I have a lot of learning to do, but this works.

```
angular.module('vah').directive("captcha", ($timeout, $parse) ->
  restrict: "A"
  require: '?ngModel'
  link: (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) ->
    return if !ngModel

    optionsObj = {
      length: 5
    }

    $timeout(->
      attrs.foo = $('#captcha_hash')
      hashSet = $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign
      scope.$watch(attrs.foo.val(), (newVal) ->
        hashSet(scope, newVal)
      )
    , 300)
    element.realperson(optionsObj)

)
```

Also, I'll include the ruby code for hashing of this particular captcha, since I ran into problems with Bignum and ruby compared to the way it's done in javascript, or their PHP/Java examples.

```
module CaptchaHashing
  module ClassMethods
    def rp_hash(value)
      hash_value = 5381
      value = value.upcase
      value.chars.each do |c|
        hash_value = ((left_shift_32(hash_value, 5)) + hash_value) + c.ord
        puts hash_value
      end
      hash_value
    end

    def left_shift_32 x, shift_amount
      shift_amount &= 0x1F
      x <<= shift_amount
      x &= 0xFFFFFFFF 

      if (x & (1<<31)).zero?
       x
      else
       x - 2**32
      end
    end

  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

and

```
def self.valid_captcha?(captcha_hash, captcha_input)
    if captcha_hash.present? && captcha_input.present?
      rp_hash(captcha_input) == captcha_hash
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Good luck!